# Same Function, Work Fine in Server 1 and Fail in Server 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following function,

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))     
    returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(8000))
as     
begin
    set @String = RTRIM(LTRIM(@String))
    declare @idx int     
    declare @slice varchar(8000)     

    select @idx = 1     
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return     

    while @idx!= 0     
    begin     
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)     
        if @idx!=0     
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)     
        else     
            set @slice = @String     

        if(len(@slice)>0)
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)     

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)     
        if len(@String) = 0 break     
    end 
return     
end
```

In server 1 it works fine but in server 2 it shows me error at,

```
if(len(@slice)>0)
    insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice) 
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Split, Line 21
Invalid column name 'Items'.
```

**Edit:** I ran `sp_server_info` and found that server1 `IDENTIFIER_CASE    = MIXED` and server2  `IDENTIFIER_CASE = SENSITIVE`, also server1 `COLLATION_SEQ = charset=iso_1 sort_order=nocase_iso charset_num=1 sort_order_num=52` and server2 `COLLATION_SEQ = charset=cp437 sort_order=bin_cp437 charset_num=3 sort_order_num=30`

Comment: The collation are same for both but it seems column name are case sensitive

Comment: Sounds like you're working in a case sensitive collation in the second case. Try `items` instead of `Items`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, it works but I want to change the server to make the column name case insensitive. My db collation are same on both server, `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, can I install another SQL Server 2012 on the same server with different instance

Comment: What's the collation of tempdb on both servers?

Comment: In server1 `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` and server2 `SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_BIN` See my edit also.

Comment: So, do you want to spend hours trying to find a workaround, when you can just fix your code so that it works in both case-sensitive and case-insensitive servers by just being consistent in your casing?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, the above one was just an example. I have hundred of SP and Functions. I don't want to change. Also, if I change this then in future there are lot of chances that this error occur. I have installed a new instance for now.